# whether flink supports suspend a flink job?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

i am just beginning learning apache flink and meet the folling problem:
How can i suspend a flink job and then resume it ? 
does flink support suspend a job using command line ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you certainly can do this with Flink. You want to read about [savepoints](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/savepoints.html), which can be triggered from the [command line](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/cli.html) or from the [REST API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/rest_api.html#cancel-job-with-savepoint).

**Updated**

Normally the goal of a stream processor is to do continuous, immediate processing of new elements as they become available. If you want to suspend processing, then I guess this might be with the goal of ignoring the source(s) for a while and dropping the arriving events, or with a desire to conserve computing resources for a time and to later resume without losing any input.

`RichCoFlatmap` and `CoProcessFunction` are building blocks you might find useful. You could setup a control stream connected to a socket (for example), and when you want to "suspend" the primary stream, send an event that causes the primary stream to either start dropping its input, or do a blocking read, or sleep, for example.

Or you might think about adding your own layer of abstraction on top of jobs, and cope with the fact that the jobids will change. Note that jobs can have names that remain unchanged across savepoints/restarts.

Comment: Thinks for answering, as far as i know, start a job with savepoints will create a new job,which will have diffent jobID, though using savepoint. I meant without changing jobID, we can stop a job and then resum it.

Comment: I see. Why is it a problem that you would end up with a new job? While I don't see how to do precisely what you ask, perhaps if you explain in more detail what you hope to accomplish, we can find a way to approximate it. (Also, are you using batch, or streaming?)

Comment: "Why is it a problem that you would end up with a new job?" for this question, I'am doing a project which takes the jobId as unique key and will stay unchanged till the job ended or deleted. for example, we create a flink stream job with id xxxx, then supspend it, after a while, we want to resume it. however, flink now use stop/cancel to suspend a job, and resume it by run the job again with savepoints, however, now jobID is not xxxx, so, i wander if there is a solution to keep jobId the same ?  thinks , btw,  what i mentioned above only involved stream job. thinks

Comment: It's not clear why this kind of suspension is desirable, but I've expanded my answer with some ideas about how to approximate this behavior.

Comment: @DavidAnderson In the solution you described, will the dropped events resumable? For example, if I'm using the Kafka source and want to pause the stream, dropping the events may still cause the Kafka offset to advance, hence being recorded in the save points. When I resume the job from the save point, the dropped events won't be replayed. Is there anyway I can signal the source to drop events and *not* advance the offset? Thanks.

Comment: Let's say when a control message arrives, the job calls the flink api to stop itself with savepoint. But the savepoint can not be completed when the process operator hangs there. Even the api invocation is async and the operator sleeps to yield cpu time, it can not be completed unless the operator exits its sleeping loop. I ask this question because the following messages in flow should only be processed after the job is restarted with configurations modified outside the job in my scenario.